# Как отсеять целочисленные площади и вещественные

Tags: c++

Нужно составить программу вычисления n Героновых треугольников где длины сторон последовательные целые числа и площадь тоже,проблема с вычислением площади треугольников такая:мне нужно чтобы печатались только целые площади с последовательными целыми сторонами,например ввожу 5:
a=3 b=4 b=5 s=6

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>


using namespace std;
int n, m;
int p = 0;
int a = 0;
int b = 1;
int c = 2;
double s = 0;

int main() {
    cout << "Vvedite n:";
    cin >> n;
    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i += 1, a += 1, b += 1, c += 1) {
        p = (a + b + c) / 2;
        s = p * (p - a) * (p - b) * (p - c);
        s = sqrt(s);
        cout << "a=" << a << " b=" << b << " c=" << c << "  the area of triangle" << s << endl;
    }
}
```

что мне нужно добавить чтобы получить нужный результат?

Answer (score 0):

Ну, если вы не поняли предыдущий ответ, давайте по-простому, тупым перебором. Хотя в предыдущем ответе было все очень четко - какие именно три последовательные числа могут давать Геронов треугольник. Это достаточно редкие числа, но если вам хочется перебирать миллионы чисел вместо того, чтоб просто вывести очередной треугольник - пожалуйста:

```
int main()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    for(int j = 1, i = 1; j <= n; ++i)
    {
        unsigned long long p = 3*i+3;
        if (p%2) continue;
        p /= 2;
        p = p*(p-i)*(p-i-1)*(p-i-2);
        unsigned long long s = sqrt(p) + 0.1;
        if (p != s*s) continue;
        cout << "a = " << i << ", b = " << i+1 << ", c = "
            << i+2 << ":  s = " << s << "\n";
        ++j;
    }
}
```

Только не вводите `n` больше 10...